# How to transpose the given table?

Tags: sql, pivot

Input

```
Activity    1   2   3   4   5
a1          1   4   72  336 336
a2          48  48  168 336 336
a3          48  48  168 336 336
a4          1   4   72  336 336
a5          672 672 672 672 672
```

Output :

```
Activity    Category    values 
a1             1        1
a1             2        4
a1             3        72
a1             4        336
a1             5        336
a2             1        48
a2             2        48
a2             3        168
a2             4        336
a2             5        336
```

Comment: which dbms (mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql) you are using? please tag your question.

Comment: What happened to activities 3, 4, and 5?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to convert this certain table into another table structure it is possible as in one-time action.

STEP 1: Create script to generate INSERT INTO syntaxes into SQL file. There are many ways to do it.

STEP 2. Execute the generated SQL syntaxes into the selected database.

We dub this as "parsing".